# Dual Monitor - Connect all edges (Windows)

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

Is it possible to connect two monitors on all edges. What i mean by that is when you hit the top of the screen the mouse should enter the bottom of the second screen. If you hit the bottom it should enter the top of the second screen and the same for left and right.

Comment: Just be aware that this may cause weird behavior if you try to drag a window through the bottom or top.

Answer (score 1):

Such a thing makes no sense given the x-y coordinates your display subsystem usually implements. It's technically possible, but it have to be would take a custom driver for your video card to do it, and given that it makes no sense and that Microsoft is wildly unlikely to sign such a thing, I seriously doubt you'll find one.

Comment: Take a look at http://access.uoa.gr/ATHENA/eng/applications/view/23

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few programs that allow you to do this, the simplest and best I've found is this AutoHotKey script. I copied the script below in case of future broken links: 
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/34427-yet-another-mouse-wrapper-this-one-supports-multi-heads/

Install [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) and run the script, or you can compile it into a .exe to run on any computer. (i.e. even without AutoHotKey installed)

**Fwd:**

```
/*
 * MouseWrapper v1.2
 *
 * Description:
 *  Allows full mouse-wrapping in virtually any single or multi-monitor environment.
 *  Double-clicking the Tray icon shows a floating tooltip that gives you boundry information
 *  You can toggle the Tooptip, Vertical and Horizontal wrapping and can pause the wrapper.
 *  Basic configuration options are stored in a file that you can edit.
 *  The mouse position and display configuration polling times can only be set via the file.
 *
 * Changelog:
 *  v1.2
 *   Screen configuration is checked periodically for alterations.
 *   Added Tooltip info and tray menu toggles
 *   Added option for vertical wrapping
 *  v1.1
 *   No longer relies on Hard offsets.
 *  v1.0
 *   Initial Release
 *
 * Known Issues/Todo:
 *  Cannot wrap on edge of a smaller monitor if that edge is inline with a larger monitor's.
 *   Example: if you have 1280x1024 and 1024x768 in Right & Left position, you cannot wrap
 *    vertically on the 1024x768 screen since the top or bottom boundry is within 1280x1024
 *   Solution: actively track which monitor i'm in, how big it is and whether or not there is
 *    anything beyond it.
 *  If the tray menu is active the position polling etc halts.
 *
 * Contact/Etc:
 *  Author: Paegus (paegus@gmail.com)
 *  Program: AutoHotKey (https://ahknet.autohotkey.com)
 *  Released under GNU General Public Licence
 */
```

**App**

```
; ------------------ Details ------------------ ;

AppName = MouseWrapper
AppVer = 1.2

; ------------------ Default Settings ------------------ ;

Default_bHWrap = true
Default_bVWrap = false
bShowTip = false
Default_PollTimeMouse = 50
Default_PollTimeDisplay = 2000

; ------------------ Read existing settings if any ------------------ ;

SettingsFile = %AppName%.ini

IfExist %SettingsFile%
{
    ; Read Settings
    FileReadLine bHWrap, %SettingsFile%, 1
    FileReadLine bVWrap, %SettingsFile%, 2
    FileReadLine PollTimeMouse, %SettingsFile%, 3
    FileReadLine PollTimeDisplay, %SettingsFile%, 4

    ;MsgBox bHWrap : %bHWrap%`nbVWrap : %bVWrap%`nPollTimeMouse : %PollTimeMouse%`nPollTimeDisplay : %PollTimeDisplay%
    if bHWrap <> true
    {
        if bHWrap <> false
        {
            Error = Invalid value on line 1: %bHWrap%
            bHWrap := Default_bHWrap
        }
    }

    if bVWrap <> true
    {
        if bVWrap <> false
        {
            Error = %Error%`nInvalid value on line 2: %bVWrap%
            bVWrap := Default_bVWrap
        }
    }

    if PollTimeMouse is not integer
    {
        Error = %Error%`nInvalid value on line 3: %PollTimeMouse%
        PollTimeMouse := Default_PollTimeMouse
    }
    else if PollTimeMouse < 10
    {
        Error = %Error%`nInvalid value on line 3: %PollTimeMouse%
        PollTimeMouse := Default_PollTimeMouse
    }

    if PollTimeDisplay is not integer
    {
        Error = %Error%`nInvalid value on line 4: %PollTimeDisplay%.
        PollTimeDisplay := Default_PollTimeDisplay
    }
    else if PollTimeDisplay < 100
    {
        Error = %Error%`nInvalid value on line 4: %PollTimeDisplay%.
        PollTimeDisplay := Default_PollTimeDisplay
    }

    ;MsgBox bHWrap : %bHWrap%`nbVWrap : %bVWrap%`nPollTimeMouse : %PollTimeMouse%`nPollTimeDisplay : %PollTimeDisplay%
    if Error
    {
        MsgBox 262192, %AppName%: Error, %Error%
    }

}
else
{
    ; Set Defaults
    bHWrap := Default_bHWrap
    bVWrap := Default_bVWrap
    PollTimeMouse := Default_PollTimeMouse
    PollTimeDisplay := Default_PollTimeDisplay

    ; Write Defaults
    FileAppend %bHWrap%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend %bVWrap%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend %PollTimeMouse%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend %PollTimeDisplay%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend `nLine 1: Horizontal Wrapping <true|false>`nLine 2: Vertical Wrapping <true|false>`nLine 3: Mouse Poll-time <milliseconds>`nLine 4: Display configuration Poll-time <milliseconds>, %SettingsFile%

    MsgBox 262208,%AppName%: Launch,This is the first time you've launched %AppName%.`nDefault settings loaded. The settings file is located at:`n`n%A_WorkingDir%\%SettingsFile%
}

; ------------------ Tray Icon & Tooltip ------------------ ;

Menu TRAY, Icon, %A_WinDir%\system32\main.cpl,,1
Menu TRAY, Tip, %AppName% v%AppVer%
Menu TRAY, NoStandard
Menu TRAY, Add, &About, MenuINFO
Menu TRAY, Add
Menu TRAY, Add, Mouse: %PollTimeMouse%ms, MenuNULL
Menu TRAY, Disable, Mouse: %PollTimeMouse%ms
Menu TRAY, Add, Disp: %PollTimeDisplay%ms, MenuNULL
Menu TRAY, Disable, Disp: %PollTimeDisplay%ms
Menu TRAY, Add
Menu TRAY, Add, &Tooltip, MenuTTT
Menu TRAY, Add, &X-Wrap, MenuTHW
Menu TRAY, Add, &Y-Wrap, MenuTVW
Menu TRAY, Add, &Pause, MenuPAUSE
Menu TRAY, Add, &Edit, MenuEDIT
Menu TRAY, Add, &Reload, MenuRELOAD
Menu TRAY, Add
Menu TRAY, Add, &Quit, MenuQUIT
Menu TRAY, Default, &About

if bShowTip = true
{
    Menu TRAY, Check, &Tooltip
}
if bHWrap = true
{
    Menu TRAY, Check, &X-Wrap
}
if bVWrap = true
{
    Menu TRAY, Check, &Y-Wrap
}

; ------------------ Inner Workings ------------------ ;

CoordMode Mouse, Screen

#SingleInstance force

#Persistent
    SetTimer ScreenUpdate, %PollTimeDisplay%
    SetTimer ScreenWrap, %PollTimeMouse%
return

; ------------------ Tray Menus ------------------ ;

MenuNULL:
return

MenuTTT:
    if bShowTip = true
    {
        bShowTip = false
        Menu TRAY, UnCheck, &Tooltip
        Tooltip
    }
    else
    {
        bShowTip = true
        Menu TRAY, Check, &Tooltip
    }
return

MenuTHW:
    if bHWrap = true
    {
        bHWrap = false
        Menu TRAY, UnCheck, &X-Wrap
    }
    else
    {
        bHWrap = true
        Menu TRAY, Check, &X-Wrap
    }

    ; Update File
    FileDelete %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend %bHWrap%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend %bVWrap%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend %PollTimeMouse%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend %PollTimeDisplay%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend `nLine 1: Horizontal Wrapping <true|false>`nLine 2: Vertical Wrapping <true|false>`nLine 3: Mouse Poll-time <milliseconds>`nLine 4: Display configuration Poll-time <milliseconds>, %SettingsFile%
return

MenuTVW:
    if bVWrap = true
    {
        bVWrap = false
        Menu TRAY, UnCheck, &Y-Wrap
    }
    else
    {
        bVWrap = true
        Menu TRAY, Check, &Y-Wrap
    }

    ; Update File
    FileDelete %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend %bHWrap%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend %bVWrap%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend %PollTimeMouse%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend %PollTimeDisplay%`n, %SettingsFile%
    FileAppend `nLine 1: Horizontal Wrapping <true|false>`nLine 2: Vertical Wrapping <true|false>`nLine 3: Mouse Poll-time <milliseconds>`nLine 4: Display configuration Poll-time <milliseconds>, %SettingsFile%
return

MenuINFO:
    MsgBox 262208,%AppName%: Info,%AppName% v%AppVer%`n`nCreated by Paegus (peagus@gmail.com)`n`nUsing AutoHotKey v%A_AhkVersion%`n`nhttp://www.autohotkey.com
return

MenuPAUSE:
    if A_IconTip = %AppName% v%AppVer%
    {
        Menu TRAY, Icon, %A_WinDir%\system32\SHELL32.dll,110,1
        Menu TRAY, Tip, %AppName% v%AppVer%`n    -  PAUSED  -
        Menu TRAY, Check, &Pause
        Pause
    }
    else
    {
        Menu TRAY, Icon, %A_WinDir%\system32\main.cpl,,1
        Menu TRAY, Tip, %AppName% v%AppVer%
        Menu TRAY, UnCheck, &Pause
        Pause
    }
return

MenuEDIT:
    run notepad %A_WorkingDir%\%SettingsFile%
return

MenuReload:
    Reload
return

MenuQUIT:
    ExitApp 0
return

; ------------------ Core Functions ------------------ ;

ScreenUpdate:
    SysGet Monitors, MonitorCount

    iBorderLeft = 0
    iBorderRight = 0
    iBorderTop = 0
    iBorderBottom = 0
    TipString = Monitors...

    Loop, %Monitors%
    {
        SysGet Monitor, Monitor, %A_Index%

        if MonitorLeft < %iBorderLeft%
        {
            ;MsgBox %A_Index%'s Left %MonitorLeft% < %iBorderLeft%
            iBorderLeft := MonitorLeft
        }

        if MonitorRight > %iBorderRight%
        {
            ;MsgBox %A_Index%'s Right %MonitorRight% > %iBorderRight%
            iBorderRight := MonitorRight - 1
        }

        if MonitorTop < %iBorderTop%
        {
            ;MsgBox %A_Index%'s Top %MonitorTop% < %iBorderTop%
            iBorderTop := MonitorTop
        }

        if MonitorBottom > %iBorderBottom%
        {
            ;MsgBox %A_Index%'s Bottom %MonitorBottom% > %iBorderBottom%
            iBorderBottom := MonitorBottom - 1
        }

        if bShowTip = true
        {
            TipString = %TipString%`n%A_Index%: %MonitorLeft%`,%MonitorTop% x %MonitorRight%`,%MonitorBottom%
        }
    }
return

ScreenWrap:
    MouseGetPos PosX, PosY
    if bHWrap = true
    {
        if PosX <= %iBorderLeft%
        {
            NPosX := iBorderRight - 1
            MouseMove %NPosX%, %PosY%, 0
        }
        else if PosX >= %iBorderRight% 
        {
            NPosX := iBorderLeft + 1
            MouseMove %NPosX%, %PosY%, 0
        }
    }

    if bVWrap = true
    {
        if PosY <= %iBorderTop%
        {
            NPosY := iBorderBottom - 1
            MouseMove %PosX%, %NPosY%, 0
        }
        else if PosY >= %iBorderBottom% 
        {
            NPosY := iBorderTop + 1
            MouseMove %PosX%, %NPosY%, 0
        }
    }

    if bShowTip = true
    {
        ToolTip Boundries...`nX: %iBorderLeft% < %PosX% > %iBorderRight%`nY: %iBorderTop% < %PosY% > %iBorderBottom%`n%TipString%
    }
return

; ------------------ End ------------------ ;
```

Comment: Mouse-wrapping is one thing, but it makes no sense to do that unless the coordinate system is similarly "wrapped" for every app.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan I'm not sure what you mean. The question was about wrapping from screen edge to screen edge, not within apps.

Comment: It makes no sense to have one coordinate system for the mouse and another for apps.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Sorry, still not understanding. If you're commenting on the code, I did not write it. Perhaps it can be improved but it works just fine for me. If you're commenting on the original question, then I think we are understanding the question differently. Can you elaborate?

Comment: "The question is about... not within apps". That's my point. It has to be within apps as well as for mouse movements. Otherwise an app window will be "torn apart" out from under the mouse pointer as it's moved past a screen edge.

Comment: You mean if you're dragging an app window to a screen edge, the mouse will wrap around to the oposite edge but the window will be "torn apart" from the mouse, and be left behind? That is not how this script behaves, try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: The University of Athens (Greece) IT department offers a link to a freeware (not Open Source) app, [Edgeless2](http://access.uoa.gr/ATHENA/eng/applications/view/23), which if installed would give you what you wish.